# How to create table with dynamic number of rows in Android

Tags: android, icons, row, tablelayout

I am trying to fill a TableLayout with a dynamic amount of rows based on an Array of icons, however i cannot get the rows to display on screen. The table should display a 5x3 grid of icons. The code I am using is below:

```
    Services serv = new Services();

    Item[] iconArray = serv.getIcons();

    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table1);

    int rowNum = iconArray.length/5;
    TableRow rows[]= new TableRow[rowNum];

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iconArray.length; i++) { 
        final String name = iconArray[i].name; 
        final int icon = iconArray[i].icon;

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon, null,false);
        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(name);

        ImageView imageicon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        imageicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do some stuff
            }
        });
        Drawable drawicon = getResources().getDrawable(icon);
        imageicon.setBackgroundDrawable(drawicon);

        if(i == 4) //End of Row
        {   
            count++;
        }
        if(i == 9) //End of Row2
        {   
            count++;
        }

        rows[count] = new TableRow(this);
        rows[count].addView(v);
        table.addView(rows[count]);
    }
```

This does not output anything to the screen and the TableLayout remains empty. Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right lines?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you just explain what your TableLayout must display? Only row with Image and TextView?

Comment: @Jahckyto The TableLayout should display three rows filled with icons and a TextView with the name of each icon. Using a GridView was not an option here for other reasons

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i will make a specific layout for my row :

**my_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"" />

</TableRow>
```

Then, i will simply fill my table with my rows in a loop :

```
static TableRow row;
Item[] iconArray = serv.getIcons();
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.table1);

for (int i = 0; i < iconArray.length; i++) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, cont, false);

    final String name = iconArray[i].name; 
    final int icon = iconArray[i].icon;

    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myText);
    text.setText(name);

    ImageView imageicon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.myImg);
    imageicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do some stuff
        }
    });
    Drawable drawicon = getResources().getDrawable(icon);
    imageicon.setBackgroundDrawable(drawicon);

    table.addView(row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I believe this is creating a new row for each icon. What I need is 3 rows in a 5x3 grid. This is my fault I didnt make this clear in my original question

Comment: Yes it creates a row per image. I don't know if you can make a Table of GridLayout, in this case it will be easy for you to draw your table